# noun as object complement, which is in S + V + O + N

Tags: complements

Considering noun object-complements, can we use prepositions in front of them at will? (S + V + O + Noun OC)

e.g. 
He elected me president./He elected me as president
He considers them hypocrites./He considers them as hypocrites.

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence?

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/consider-and-consider-as: Yes, after certain verbs like consider, elect, choose, make, see, etc. 'as' is not used.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the verb. You can do that for "to elect" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/elect_1?q=elect).

> elect somebody (as) something
>    He was elected (as) MP for Oxford East.

For other verbs you can't; you have to check the entry for the particular verb at hand so as to determine whether a preposition can be used, and which one can be.

- He made me (a/the) president. ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/make_1?q=make))

> appoint
>   ​  make somebody + noun; to elect or choose somebody as something
>   She made him her assistant.